# How to make below code more readable and efficient?

Tags: java

Code below reads static variables from `ProductConfiguration` class. Functions `setAccess` and `setMarketAccess` in two classes `ProductInitialization` and `ProductMarketInitialization` reads variables from `ProductConfiguration`. Can this reading be done in a better way? I still want to have file `ProductConfiguration` to hold public variables. Was just wondering if there is a better way of reading this variables in the other two classes, may be there in future there will be additional classes that will read variables from `ProductConfiguration`

```
public class ProductConfiguration{

      public static final PRODUCT_ACCESS=//this value is read from properties file

      public static final MARKET_PRODUCT_ACCESS=//this value is read from properties file

}


public class ProductInitialization{
    public Product setAccess(Product p){
         if(p.brand == "LOCAL") {                
             p.access=ProductConfiguration.PRODUCT_ACCESS;
             return p;
          }
         p.access = "DEFAULT";
        return p;
    }
}

public class ProductMarketInitialization{
       public void setMarketAccess(Product p){
            if(p.type == "MARKET"){               
                p.access=
              ProductConfiguration.MARKET_PRODUCT_ACCESS;
              return p;
            }
           p.access ="MARKET_DEFAULT";
          return p;
      }
}
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: This isn't related to your question exactly but you might want to change how you are comparing the strings. Strings should always be compare using equals(), so your code would be .brand.equals("LOCAL"). == compares the exact value. This works for primitives, but Strings are objects. And variables containing objects dont' really containg objects, but a reference to the object. You will learn more about this in the future, but for now if you want it to work you have use equals().

Answer (score 2):

I cannot imagine the code being that reduced; you probably removed extraneous code.
The code shown should be clearer as:

```
public class ProductInitialization {
    public void setAccess(Product p){
        p.access = p.brand.equals("LOCAL") ? ProductConfiguration.PRODUCT_ACCESS
             : "DEFAULT";
    }
}

public class ProductMarketInitialization {
    public void setMarketAccess(Product p){
        p.access = p.type.equals("MARKET") ? ProductConfiguration.MARKET_PRODUCT_ACCESS
                   : "MARKET_DEFAULT";
     }
}
```

The `ProductConfiguration` is taken from a properties file. This `PropertiesResourceBundle` is principally partly lazy. A `ListResourceBundle` would be totally immediate, as this is a java class containing arrays. If on the other hand you would like the startup as smoothly as possible, a totally lazy loading would need **getters** for the `ProductConfiguration`.

This seems still not very important, so be it.

The special cases of a brand `LOCAL` and type `MARKET`, and finally a special result `DEFAULT` and `MARKET_DEFAULT` hinting at yet another case handling are more cumbersome.

```
Old      New

LOCAL    ${productConf.productAccess}
other    Optional.empty()

MARKET   ${productConf.marketProductAccess}
other    Optional.empty()
```

So making the access field an `Optional<...>`, maybe even an optional getter.

Having two initialisation classes seems **overdesigned**, especially as they create two distinct categories of the same `Product`.

In general it seems too early to pay too much attention to *adding extra code* for nicety's sake.

```
    public void configAccessForDefault(Product p){
        p.access = p.brand.equals("LOCAL") ? ProductConfiguration.PRODUCT_ACCESS
             : "DEFAULT";
    }

    public void configAccessForMarket(Product p){
           p.access = p.type.equals("MARKET") ? ProductConfiguration.MARKET_PRODUCT_ACCESS
                   : "MARKET_DEFAULT";
     }
```